# Is VNC faster than X11 Tunneling?

Tags: ssh, vnc, tunnel

I hope this questions lies in the realm of stackoverflow (I assume it does, as these tools are required for programming from a distance).

I am curious, I hear that VNC is faster than X11 tunneling (i.e. Cygwin-X). Is this true? If so, why is this the case? My thinking was that they both boiled down to using ssh to tunnel the data from server to client. Why would one be faster than the other?

Also, if I can be so bold, what VNC utility is decent for Windows (both commercial or free).

Thanks!

Comment: There is a different in how the visible data is transferred. The outcome depends on many details, but typically VNC is faster that X11 forwarding. To keep things simple: VNC forwards the (compressed) picture you see, X11 forwarding communicates with your local X server with a protocol to tell it what drawing operations to perform. So a completly different architecture.

Comment: So then, the difference lies primarily in visualization data transfer? Would there be any difference if I were to run MATLAB with no visualization?

Comment: About "a decent VNC client for MS-Windows": this question _is_ off topic here, it is primarily opinion based, asks for a recommendation.

Comment: VNC and X11 forwarding _only_ deal with the visual stuff. I do not see why or how you want to use it for anything else. If yo only want to execute a command on the remote side and are not interested in the graphical output, then simply run it via ssh and all is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd describe my experience this way:

- X is chattier. Works poorly over a high-latency link.
- VNC is less chatty and works OK over a high-latency link.

No particular guidance on VNC client.